# This Javascript / JSON data to create three level unordered list from arrays and for-loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, for-loop

Is there a better way for creating the desired outcomes from this JSON data? can somebody help me figure out whys it working. can it be much cleaner?

```
    <div id="accordion" class="display-data">
    <!-- AJAX displays here -->
    </div>
```

Is there a better way for creating the desired outcomes from this Javascript data?

```
myObj = [
    {
        "name":"John",
        "age":30,
        "cars": [
            { "name":"Ford", 
                "models":[ 
                    "Fiesta", 
                    "Focus", 
                    "Mustang" 
                ],
            },
            { 
            "name":"BMW", 
                "models":[ 
                    "320", 
                    "X3", 
                    "X5"
                ],
            },
            { 
                "name":"Fiat", 
                "models":[ 
                    "500", 
                    "Panda" 
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"Matthew",
        "age":32,
        "cars": [
            { "name":"Ford", 
                "models":[ 
                    "Everest", 
                    "WRanger", 
                    "Mustang" 
                ],
                "colour": "Red2"
            },
            { 
            "name":"BMW", 
                "models":[ 
                    "Z Series", 
                    "X2000", 
                    "X5"
                ],
                "colour": "Green2" 
            },
            { 
                "name":"Toyota", 
                "models":[ 
                    "Camary", 
                    "Tarago" 
                ],
                "colour": "Blue2" 
            }
        ]
    }
]
      
      
      
      
var myObj, i, j, k, str = "";

for (i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {

  str += "<h1>" + myObj[i].name + "</h1>";
  str += "  <ul>";  

  for (j in myObj[i].cars) {
    str += "    <li>" + myObj[i].cars[j].name + "";
    str += "        <ul>";
    for (k in myObj[i].cars[j].models) {
      str  += " <li>" + myObj[i].cars[j].models[k] + "</li>";
    }
    str += "        </ul>"; 
    str += "    </li>"; 
  }
  str += "  </ul>";
}

document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML = str;
```

I have combined objects and arrays, its works just dont know if there is a better method.

https://jsfiddle.net/ok6570m2/1/#&togetherjs=GMGBdGE6pE

I really dont know to much about Javascript and arrays

Comment: It would be more readable with a templating engine like mustache.js. If you are using a framework, then use the framework's templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment to use the templating engine of the framework you're using, or to find a robust templating library if you'll be doing more than a little bit. Otherwise here is an example of using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to allow for more readable parsing of your data.

```
function parseEntry(entry) {
  let newEntry = `
    <h1>${entry.name}</h1>
    <ul>
      ${entry.cars.map(car => (
        `<li>${car.name} ${car.colour ? `(${car.colour})` : ''}
            <ul>
              ${car.models.map(model => (`<li>${model}</li>`)).join('')}
            </ul>
         </li>`)).join('')}
    </ul>`; 
  
  const entryDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
  entryDiv.innerHTML = newEntry;
  
  return entryDiv;
}
```

```js
const entries = [
    {
        "name":"John",
        "age":30,
        "cars": [
            { "name":"Ford", 
                "models":[ 
                    "Fiesta", 
                    "Focus", 
                    "Mustang" 
                ],
            },
            { 
            "name":"BMW", 
                "models":[ 
                    "320", 
                    "X3", 
                    "X5"
                ],
            },
            { 
                "name":"Fiat", 
                "models":[ 
                    "500", 
                    "Panda" 
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"Matthew",
        "age":32,
        "cars": [
            { "name":"Ford", 
                "models":[ 
                    "Everest", 
                    "WRanger", 
                    "Mustang" 
                ],
                "colour": "Red2"
            },
            { 
            "name":"BMW", 
                "models":[ 
                    "Z Series", 
                    "X2000", 
                    "X5"
                ],
                "colour": "Green2" 
            },
            { 
                "name":"Toyota", 
                "models":[ 
                    "Camary", 
                    "Tarago" 
                ],
                "colour": "Blue2" 
            }
        ]
    }
]
      
      
      
function parseEntry(entry) {
  let newEntry = `
    <h1>${entry.name}</h1>
    <ul>
      ${entry.cars.map(car => (
        `<li>${car.name} ${car.colour ? `(${car.colour})` : ''}
            <ul>
              ${car.models.map(model => (`<li>${model}</li>`)).join('')}
            </ul>
         </li>`)).join('')}
    </ul>`; 
  
  const entryDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
  entryDiv.innerHTML = newEntry;
  
  return entryDiv;
}

const container = document.getElementById('accordion');

entries.forEach(entry => container.appendChild(parseEntry(entry)));
```

```html
<div id="accordion" class="display-data">
</div>
```